# Top of the day to you Sir!

Tags: traduction, salutations

how you would translate " top of the day" in French as a greeting, I don't seem to get what it could be?
Thank you!

Comment: The meaning is easy to translate: "Good morning!" The feeling will require some insight from a native speaker: old-fashioned, pleasant, whimsical, big-hearted...

Answer (score 2):

It is actually difficult to assert with certitude what "top of the day" means in English, as it is obviously a late transformation of "top of the morning", a well established greeting in English and Irish English, although not used nowadays ([ref.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/297296)), not used in England, nor much used in Ireland, with which it is massively associated ([ref.](https://linguaholic.com/linguablog/top-of-the-morning-to-you/)) ; [this other reference](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51427) provides a thorough historical tracking of the expression through the ages, but fails to conclude clearly on what interpretation to assign to it ; it is even suggested that a conflating of two meanings could be an ideal interpretation for it. There is no strong evidence that it means "best part" or "early part", and at that it is not clear what this early part should be, whether dawn or some later early part in the morning.

In view of this uncertainty, the French translation cannot be but tentative.

For instance, Harrap's gives us "*Bien le bonjour*", which is another idiomatic form, in French this time. It is however colloquial ([Le Robert dictionary](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/bonjour)), whereas, as can be read in the reference about the question of the formality of "top of the morning", formality does not enter into it (by which I understand that it is neither formal nor informal).

Comment: And "top of the day to you, sir" isn't colloquial? *Top of the morning* is described as formerly working-class by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/top_of_the_morning). If that doesn't make it colloquial, then I don't know what would. It is certainly not something I would expect to hear in a formal setting in the United State.

Comment: @Peter shor I can't fathom this fact you imply by your referring to the woorking class, namely that all working class speech is necessarily colloquial; moreover, the working class is  to an appreciable extent quite capable of discriminating among various linguistic forms: we'll have very few instances of the sort "what's up Mr President!" in society past and present, even considering that there is usually not so much interaction between the parties involved. For instance, you can find the following cases (ref.): "The top of the morning to you, my Lord — The top of the   (1/2)

Comment: @Peter shor morning to you, gentlemen — The top of the morning to your honour  — The top of the morning to you, Mr. Editor". Those terms of address can't be associated with an expression that would be downright colloquial; perhaps we can talk of  a certain fluctuating trend towards colloquialism; this seems to corroborate one of the references, if I understand it properly (formality does not enter into it). (2/2).

Comment: "Bien le bonjour" would be the right way to go, in my humble opinion. Or if an antiquated XVIIIth c., stilted effect is desirable, an elliptic "... Monsieur/Madame/Messieurs." with a slight bow would also work.